# setInterval inside the gameloop, not working as intended

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm making a little canvas game but I cannot get the `setInterval` to work well inside of the gameloop.

With this code the interval runs once and then the gameloop seems to take over and runs all the time.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Gameloop
    function gameLoop(){
        update();
        draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }

    var x=50;
    var y=50;

    // update values
    function update(){
        x++;
        //timer to increase speed once every 2 seconds
        function timer(){
        x = x +5;
        }
        var interval = setInterval(timer, 2000);
    }

    //Draw onto canvas
    function draw(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,800);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(x,y,25,25);
        ctx.fill();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload=gameLoop()>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wel.. you need to do `clearInterval(intervalid)` to clear an interval. so you need to store a reference somewhere and decide when you wish to clear them.

Comment: You are starting an interval for each iteration in the game loop, so by the time that the first interval moves the box, there is about 30 more intervals running that will start moving the box right after, and there are new intervals starting all the time. Run the `update` function once instead of in the game loop.

Comment: Thanks for the awnsers, was thinking something like that aswell, tough this is not the real game just an testg ame to solve my problem so the update function handels ALOT of info in the real game so it is kinda needed.

And if i clear the interval once every gameloop iteration then it wouldnt work since it starts and get canceld many times during one second?

Comment: then get the interval out of the update function and call it only once, also, requestAnimationFrame does provide a timestamp that you could use instead of this interval.

Answer (score 1):

Each gameloop was firing another interval. Try using frame times for interval instead. Also get the canvas and context once as a global for increased frames per second.

```js
var elFps  = document.getElementById("fps");
var fps = 0;
var fpsInterval = setInterval(function(){
  elFps.innerHTML = 'fps='+fps;
  fps = 0;
}, 1000);


var speed = 1;
var gameStart = Date.now();
var speedUpTime = gameStart + 2000;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //Gameloop
    function gameLoop(){
        var frameTime = Date.now();
        if (frameTime >= speedUpTime) {
          speed+=1;
          speedUpTime += 2000;
        }
        fps++;
        update();
        draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop); // This is your looper
    }

    var x=50;
    var y=50;

    // update values
    function update(){
        x+=speed;
    }

    //Draw onto canvas
    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,800);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(x,y,25,25);
        ctx.fill();
    }

gameLoop();
```

```html
<div id="fps"> - </div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```